# Publishing PAID app in android market - India

Tags: android, google-play

I want to publish a paid app in the Android Market, but I do not see India when registering for a merchant account. How would I go about selling apps from India?

Comment: Have you tried their technical support?  This is NOT a programming question

Comment: I think that's a bit harsh. It is a question that is only of interest to our professions. The FAQ states "What kind of questions can I ask here? if your question generally covers …
<snip>matters that are unique to the programming profession
then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: Why do we have an android-market tag is this is off topic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot publish to Android Market from India yet (India is not enabled for [merchant accounts in Google Checkout](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324)). The only option would be to look at alternative Android app stores, or put up ad-supported versions, or to put it on the Market and sell the unlock code from your website.

The other options are

1. Look at alternative Android app stores.
2. Put up ad-supported versions
3. Put it on the Market and sell the unlock code from your website.